# Getting first line of string in a variable using Powershell

Tags: powershell

This line of code:

```
$eventResult = Get-EventLog -Source ".net runtime" -LogName Application -Newest 1 | select -expandproperty message
```

Outputs a very long string into $eventResult.

What I'd like to do is grab the very first line of it.

This outputs the ENTIRE content of $eventResult:

```
$eventResult | select-object -first 1
```

However, Outputting the data into a file and then parsing it works like a charm:

```
$eventResult | out-file c:\output.txt
cat c:\output.txt | select-object -first 1
```

What am I missing here?

UPDATE:
if the output is as follows:

```
 Line1...
 Line2...
 Line3...
```

Then all I want is "Line1..."

UPDATE2:

I edited the $eventResult (forgot the | select message).

Comment: Your post is a little vague with the 'first line' language.  Are you looking to grab the data without the headers? Is that what you mean by first line?

Comment: I mean literally the first line.
I'll try to rephrase.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Splitting the string on newline into an array and then taking the first of the array will work, although it might not be the most efficient.

```
($eventResult.Message -split '\n')[0]
```

Comment: Not efficient but it worked :)
Kudos to you my friend.

Comment: `(-split $eventResult.Message)[0]`

Answer (score 15):

`Select-Object` is returning the entire content of `$eventResult` because the entire content of `$eventResult` is the first object.

For the first line to be returned by this query each line in `$eventResult` needs to become its own object, e.g:

```
$eventResult.Split([Environment]::NewLine) | Select -First 1
```

Comment: Using [Environment]::NewLine is key to this code working cross platform.

Comment: `$eventResult.Split([Environment]::NewLine) | Select -Skip 1` to skip first line but obtain rest of it. More details can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1