# How to remove part of a string in powershell using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, powershell

I am struggling with a regular expression that I can't figure out:

My string is like this

```
Y

[sudo] Password for user: Other Text here
even more text here: with more text
```

My goal is to select all the text from the first line up to and including the first ': ' and to replace it with nothing.

Problem is that the first two lines might or might not be present, and it would still have to select the text up to and including the first occurrence of ': '

My end result should look like:

```
Other Text here
even more text here: with more text
```

This is what I got, but now I am stuck:

```
$Test[0..3] -replace ('[a-zA-Z]+\w\:*\s')
```

But that leaves line 0 and line 1 and doesn't get rid of [sudo] either :(

Hope a regex wiz can give me some insight :)

*EDIT*
Some more info on the actual string (which is very long and contains a unix log file):

```
C:\> $MainArray
y

[sudo] password for User: 1485673353 1 33412 2 appxxx 1801152 1801047 0 appxxx bptm image copy is not ready, retry attempt: 6 of 500 o
bject is busy, cannot be closed
1485673354 1 33412 2 appxxx 1801153 1801047 0 appxxx bptm image copy is not ready, retry attempt: 6 of 500 object is busy, cannot be closed etc. etc.
```

Trying the first answer:
 C:> $MainArray -replace ('^[^:]+?:\s*')

```
y

1485676476 1 4 4 appxxx 1801540 1801213 0 appxxx bptm successfully wrote backup id appxxx_1485671817, copy 1, fragment 17, 51200000
```

It somehow doesn't delete the first two lines (the y  and the RETURN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Regex 1 *(excluding colon)*

You can use this regular expression:

```
^[^:]+?(?=:)
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the String
- `[^:]+?` matches 1 or more characters except `:` with as few characters as possible
- `(?=:)` a positive lookahead: a colon needs to be directly after the previous match

[**Live example on *regex101***](https://regex101.com/r/lgVNDZ/1)

---

#### Regex 2 *(including colon)*

If you want to match the colon and the next space too, you can also use this regular expression:

```
^[^:]+?:\s*
```

- `:` instead of `(?=:)` includes the colon in the match
- `\s*` matches as much whitespace characters as possible (0 or more whitespace characters)

[**Live example on *regex101***](https://regex101.com/r/lgVNDZ/2)

---

#### PowerShell with Regex 2

```
$test="[sudo] password for user: other text here. even more text: sdfvsdv"
$test -replace "^[^:]+?:\s*"
```

> other text here. even more text: sdfvsdv

[image: powershell console]

Comment: Maybe include a little more context/explanation as to why this pattern works

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, just added a few lines of explanation.

Comment: Hi @ssc-hrep3 that doesn't seem to work for me:

$test[0..2] -replace ('^[^:]+?(?=:)',"")
y

: Some more text here

I do see it seems to work on REGEX101 but it still doesn't include the first ': ' in the selection there either... (EDIT: Sorry, hadn't seen your additional response)

That being said, it is already selecting more than I got, lol!

Comment: @Fredster I've updated the answer with the PowerShell commands. Why are you even using `$Test[0..3]` instead of just `$Test`?

Comment: I was using the $test[x] to try and limit it to the first 3 lines... $test[0] returns the first line (Containing Y + return), $test[1] returns the 2nd line (return) and $test[2] returns the 3rd line (That contains the [sudo] text: followed by more text)... But even not including the [0..2] leaves the first two first lines over here :(

Comment: `$Test[0]` returns the first **character** of the string, not the first line. By using the above regex, you don't have to cut the string into the first three lines, because it is only searching from the beginning of the String. If you still want to cut it into lines and only search the first `n` lines, you can use [`($Test -split "\r?\n")[0]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35872166/3233827)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Added some text to the original question to show what it produces on my side... the [2] produces a nicely delimited line of the logfile (Which was obtained in a single command). It is still a string (Judging from Get-MEmber)

Comment: @Fredster My output is different. See the updated answer.

Comment: I see indeed... I guess the difference is in how the $Mainarray is built in the first place (It is filled in one go, by using a PLINK command to coonect to the remote UNIX server)...  It acts like:  C:\> $test="sentence one","sentence two", "sentence 3"


 C:\> $test[1]
sentence two

Comment: Okay, I see. Your variable contains an array of Strings and not a single String with linebreaks. The question now is, what do you want to do exactly, because there are only two possibilities: combining the single strings of 2 up to all lines and then use a regex for this combination or just use a regex for every line alone, no matter what the previous or next line contains. A regex can only be used on a single String, not an array of Strings.

Comment: ok, that makes it clear to me: As the MainArray is variable in length and contains many, many lines (And is an array of separate strings), I can't combine it into one long string, so REGEX seems out of the question if I understand you correctly. What is odd though, is that mainarray|gm -verbose still tells me it is a SYSTEM.STRING (Even though it acts like an array?!?). Thank you: Your help has been great and I will mark it as answered

Comment: Yes, that's correct, PowerShell seems to flatten the array to its contents. I just found [this link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/a35N1ogYZBM/NNAcY-YkMV4J) and [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/13/powertip-find-array-members-with-get-member-in-powershell/), which are saying, putting a `,` in front of the command shows the correct type: `,$test | gm -verbose`