# How to write a regular expression in PowerShell - find specific string in filename and remove everything what comes after it

Tags: powershell

I want to write a powershell script which should be able to remove searched string and everything after the searched string from a filename.

My code looks like this:

```
$path = "U:\PowerShell_Scripts\Test files"
$text1 = "_FULL.001_020_"
$text2 = "_HIGH.001_020_"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "*$text1*" -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $text1, ''}
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "*$text2*" -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $text2, ''}
```

but it is not doing what I need of course. I have been looking the whole day via google, but this particular method is not possible to find, or I am using probably wrong search criteria.

Filenames which names should be manipulated:

```
SVT_ALL_HU__MGU_01__FULL.001_020_040.xml
SVT_ALL_HU__MGU_01__FULL.001_020_080.xml
SVT_ALL_HU__MGU_01__HIGH.001_020_249.xml
```

This is not a duplicate of ["How to remove part of a string in powershell using Regular Expressions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934659/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string-in-powershell-using-regular-expressions), because there is no multiple filename manipulation mentioned with starting fixed string.

Comment: Have you looked at PowerShell's own help on regex? [`Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Regular_Expressions?view=powershell-5.1) may be useful here - but remember that PowerShell is not a Linux shell, and requires a different mindset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove part of a string in powershell using Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934659/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string-in-powershell-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: Please read up on [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) and how they differ from [globbing expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088.aspx).

Comment: Aside from the dot matching any character as a RegEx I don't see a problem with your code. Here the files got renamed to `SVT_ALL_HU__MGU_01_040.xml SVT_ALL_HU__MGU_01_080.xml SVT_ALL_HU__MGU_01_249.xml` in a test. So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is the rest is still there in the filename. I want to find that specific string and then delete this string and everything what comes after that string. Beside that I need to make parallel process with same file, because the files are coming from developers with some funny stuff at start of filename (like: [{[]}]) which I need to delete manually and thats very annoying if I need to process over hundred files. Thatswhy I am asking for help, because I am not working with Regexp on everyday basis.

Answer (score -2):

This should do what you're requesting:

```
$path = "U:\PowerShell_Scripts\Test files"
$text1 = "_FULL.001_020_"
$text2 = "_HIGH.001_020_"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "*$text1*" -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '__F.*\.','.')
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "*$text2*" -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '__H.*\.','.')
```

It will take `SVT_ALL_HU__MGU_01__FULL.001_020_080.xml` and make it `SVT_ALL_HU__MGU_01.xml`

Comment: This is not working. I've tried it at home, even moved the directory outside from "C:\Users" to enhance naming compatibility to C:\Test\Files, but nothing happens with files when I run the code.

Comment: @PavolDurica Edited to remove script blocks.  Those shouldn't be there.

Comment: Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Test\File_rename2.ps1:4 char:78
+ ... t1*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '__F.*\.','.')
+                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingValidationExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft. 
   PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: You MUST use scriptblocks there. Parentheses won't work, because with them PowerShell won't defer the expansion of `$_` (i.e. `$_` is expanded when the `Get-ChildItem ... | Rename-Item ...` statement is parsed rather than when `Rename-Item` is invoked).